# Order of an element in the quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I am stuck in an exercise of Rose's group theory book, (page 43 exercise 106 (ii) ). The exercise is as follows. Suppose that $K\unlhd G$ with $|K|=m$. Let $x$ be an element of $G$ and $n$ be a positive integer co-prime with $m$. Prove that if $o(xK)=n$ then there is an element $y$ of $G$ such that $o(y)=n$ and $xK=yK$, ($xK$ and $yK$ are viewed as elements of the group $G/K$).

All I could do was to show that there exists an element $y$ where $o(y)=n$ and $\langle yK\rangle=\langle xK\rangle $. For that notice that $o(xK)=n\mid o(x)=b$ because $(xK)^b$$=(x^b)K=1\cdot K=K$. Thus for $λ=\frac{o(x)}{n}$ and $y=x^λ$ we have $o(y)=n$ and because $(n,m)=1$, $o(yK)=n$ too, (thats exercise 106 (i)). Obviously $yK$ is an element of $\langle xK\rangle $ , thus $\langle yK\rangle \subseteq \langle xK\rangle $ and from orders we get the equality. I don't know if thats the right direction to solve the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general property of a finite group $G$ that if $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$ for group elements $a,b\in G$, then $a=b^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Apply that to what you have already shown for $G/K$ and you get $xK=(yK)^k=y^kK$. Therefore, $y^k$ is the element you are looking for.

**Update:**

Let $z:=y^k$. Then $z^n=(y^k)^n=(y^n)^k=1$ since $y^n=1$, so $o(z)$ divides $n$. Assume that $m:=o(z)$ is strictly smaller than $n$. Then also $(zK)^m=z^kK=K$, so $o(zK)<n$, a contradiction.

Therefore $o(y)=n$.

Comment: And how you can ensure that $o(y^k)=n$?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, I may have been a bit too brief. I edited my post to show why $o(n)=n$.

Comment: Hmm, i cant find the contradiction. $z=y^k=x^{λk}$ where $λ=\frac{o(x)}{n}$. We have from the hypothesis that $o(xK)=n$ so $x^{λk}$$K$ can have order smaller than n. Am i missing something?